# Update struct variable based on the other variable from same struct

Tags: solidity, struct, solidity-0.8.x

I'm trying to create a contract with a struct (`Category`) containing an array of another structs (`Item`). `Item` struct has a boolean variable `minted` with a default value of `false`. I'd like to change that variable to `true` after a token is minted.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Test {
    uint256 mintPrice = 50000000 gwei;

    struct Item {
        uint256 code;
        bool minted;
    }

    struct Category {
        string name;
        Item[] items;
    }

    mapping (string => Category) public categories;

    constructor() {
        // Create test categories with custom `Item` codes
        uint[] memory i = new uint[](3);
        i[0] = 4;
        i[1] = 5;
        i[2] = 9;
        createCategory("Test", i);

        uint[] memory j = new uint[](4);
        j[0] = 121;
        j[1] = 131;
        j[2] = 132;
        j[3] = 141;
        createCategory("Test2", j);
    }

    function createCategory(string memory categoryName, uint[] memory itemIds) public {
        Category storage c = categories[categoryName];
        c.name = categoryName;

        for (uint i = 0; i < itemIds.length; i++) {
            Item memory item = Item(itemIds[i], false);
            c.items.push(item);
        }
    }

    function getCategory(string memory categoryName) public view returns (string memory name, Item[] memory items) {
        Category storage c = categories[categoryName];
        return (c.name, c.items);
    }

    function getUnminted(string memory categoryName) public view returns (uint256 itemId) {
        // Find the first available "code" in current category
        uint256 unmintedItemId;
        Category storage c = categories[categoryName];
        for (uint i = 0; i < c.items.length; i++) {
            if (c.items[i].minted == false) {
                unmintedItemId = c.items[i].code;
                break;
            }
        }
        return unmintedItemId;
    }

    function mint(string memory categoryName) public payable {
        Category storage c = categories[categoryName];
        uint256 unmintedID = getUnminted(categoryName);

        // Category must be valid (must have items)
        require(c.items.length > 0, "Invalid category");

        // Category must have available items to mint
        require(unmintedID > 0, "No tokens available");

        // Amount must be valid
        require(msg.value == mintPrice, "Invalid amount");

        // mint the actual token (by using safeMint() from OpenZeppelin or similar function)

        // Change Item's "minted" variable to "true"
        Item storage currentItem = c.items[unmintedID];  // Obviously not working
        currentItem.minted = true;
    }
}
```

As commented in my code, in `mint()` function, after the token gets minted, I would like to change variable `minted` in `Item` with specific `code` to `true`. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `getUnminted` so it returns the index of the first unminted `Item` instead of its `code`. With that you then use this index to access the `Item` in the items array of the Category.

updated `getUnminted` function:

```js
function getUnminted(string memory categoryName) public view returns (uint256 itemIndex) {
    // Find the first available "code" in current category
    Category storage c = categories[categoryName];
    for (uint i = 0; i < c.items.length; i++) {
        if (c.items[i].minted == false) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    revert("No tokens available");
}
```

updated `mint` function:

```
function mint(string memory categoryName) public payable {
    Category storage c = categories[categoryName];
    uint256 unmintedIndex = getUnminted(categoryName);

    // Category must be valid (must have items)
    require(c.items.length > 0, "Invalid category");

    // Amount must be valid
    require(msg.value == mintPrice, "Invalid amount");

    // Mint the actual token (by using safeMint() from OpenZeppelin or similar function)

    // Change Item's "minted" variable to "true"
    Item storage currentItem = c.items[unmintedIndex];
    currentItem.minted = true;
}
```

Comment: That's a very good idea, I actually changed it a bit more, returning the whole `Item` struct in my `getUnminted()` function, I think it will be more useful in other places in the contract. I just had to change `getUnminted()` to `internal` so I can return `Item storage unmintedItem` and then in `mint()` function changed the second line to `Item storage unmintedItem = getUnminted(categoryName);`. In the end of `mint()`, I modify it with `unmintedItem.minted = true;`. Thanks for help!

Comment: sounds good! you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you ask how to access the bool from Category you can do something like this:

```
    function mint()public {
    categories["one"].items[1].minted = true;
}
```